# How to create multiple objects of an extended class

Tags: java

I made a class which extends JPanel. Now I want to create multiple objects of it. How can I do this?

```
JPanel[] panel = new PanelDraggable [i] (100,100,100,150,scroll);
```

is not working. Maybe making the class not extended and return `JPanel[]`?

```
public PanelDraggable( int x,  int y, int width, int height, String lblName, JComponent comp) {

    //        draggable.setCursor(draggable.getCursor());
    //        setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));

    closeDim = 15;
    headerHeight = 20;
    adjust= 2;

    setBounds(x, y, width, height);
    this.setLayout(null);
    setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(40, 49, 151), adjust, true));
    this.setOpaque(true);

    //header
    header = new JLabel("   "+lblName);
    this.add(header);
    header.setBounds(0, 0, width-(closeDim + 4), headerHeight);
    MouseInputAdapter mouseAdapter = new HeaderMouseHandler();
    header.addMouseMotionListener(mouseAdapter);
    header.addMouseListener(mouseAdapter);

    //close Button
    close = new JLabel();
    close.setIcon(new ImageIcon("icons/close_16x16.png"));
    close.setBounds( (width- (closeDim + 4)) , 4, closeDim, closeDim);
    close.setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
    this.add(close);

    MouseInputAdapter closeMouseAdapter = new CloseMouseHandler();
    close.addMouseListener(closeMouseAdapter);

    //Container
    cs = new JPanel();
    cs.setBounds(adjust, headerHeight, width - (adjust*2), (height-headerHeight-adjust) );
    cs.setOpaque(true);
    this.add(cs);
    cs.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    cs.add(comp, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    //Resise
    resize = new JLabel();
    resize.setBounds( (width-closeDim), (height-closeDim) , closeDim, closeDim);
    resize.setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.SE_RESIZE_CURSOR));
    this.add(resize);

    MouseInputAdapter resizeMouseAdapter = new ResizeMouseHandler();
    resize.addMouseMotionListener(resizeMouseAdapter);


}
```

Comment: Obviously `JPanel[] panel = new PanelDraggable [i] (100,100,100,150,scroll)` will not work. First do `JPanel[] panel = new PanelDraggable [i]` and the add a `new PanelDraggable(100,100,100,150,scroll)` to panel array.

Comment: thanks a lot for quick answer!

Answer (score 3):

First, declare an array of the desired `object`-

```
PanelDraggable[] panel = new PanelDraggable [size];
```

Next, insantiate each object -

```
for (int i=0; i<=size; i++) {
  panel[i] = new PanelDraggable(Your params here);
}
```